# Dynamically reload the URLConfs for a running site

Tags: python, django

I have a django site. Like all standard sites, it uses URLConfs to associate URLs with views. However, in addition to that, I have some URL configs which I dynamically generate from data in the database. Everything works as I would like it.

Is it possible to reload all the URLConfs while the site is running, from code? In case someone updates the database and change some of the URLs in the site, I would like to trigger a "rediscovery" of all the URLs. This would cause my code to dynamically re-create the URLs from the data in the DB.

Currently, the generated URLs can be anywhere in the URL hierarchy. They are not all under one prefix, such as /`dynamic/` or such. However, if this is absolutely necessary to do what I need to get done, I can place all the dynamic URLs under one prefix.

Some downtime is allowed for the site while the rediscovery of URLs take place.

How would I trigger such a reloading of all the URLConfs?

Comment: I had to do exactly the same thing on The Texas Tribune. We used the redirects framework to support our old URL scheme while implementing a new one, and it worked like a charm. It might not be an exact fit for your needs, but might give you some ideas.

Comment: It is not necessary to maintain old urls and redirect them to new ones. I guess my problem is simpler. When someone adds a new db entry which would correspond to a new URL, how do I reload the URLConfs. Currently, I have a url.py file which creates urlpatterns from the DB. How would I trigger the reloading of all urlpatterns from code?

Comment: What about making your urlpatterns a property with a getter that gets called every time Django accesses it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question starts from a premise that most Django programmers wouldn't accept: that you can or should create URLs dynamically from the database. If you're doing that, you're doing it wrong.

Your URL patterns are part of the code, not the data. Obviously, the URLs themselves are formed by combining the patterns with the data - eg `foo/<slug>/bar/`, but this doesn't need reloading when new slugs are added because it is resolved by the view, not the URL processor.

Comment: I agree with Daniel. Even on The Tribune, we weren't dynamically generating patterns; they were defined in urls.py. +1 for you Daniel.

Comment: I understand that I am not following the paradigm set by Django. However, real world requirements are such: 1. Business user can dynamically edit and (rarely) add new pages. 2. Pages have URL paths that can be anywhere in the site hierarchy 3. URLs must be SEO friendly and follow the law of least surprise (prefer /aboutus/ instead of /dyn/aboutus/, with everything after the /dyn/ being a slug).

Comment: The flatpages app gives me essentially what I need, but it is missing a few pieces of custom functionality, and, it is not possible to reference URLs by name when using it. I see that a compromise will need to be made on something. Now, keeping in mind that I am doing it wrong, is it possible to trigger the regeneration of URLs from URL confs after the site has been initialized?

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys    
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import clear_url_caches

clear_url_caches()
reload(sys.modules[settings.ROOT_URLCONF])
```